# IF FORMULA FOR EXPIRE-NEAR EXPIRE AND FRESH

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, if

Hope you all are doing well.

I need a formula for one of my sheets having data of different medicines. I have to bifurcate products by their expiry status. Fresh, Near Expired, Expired. Here I get to define what is the criteria to apply any of these categories. obviously, a product's expiry date is equal to or less than current date it is expire. A product's expiry date is less than six months from current date this falls under near expiry category and if a product's expiry date is above 6 months from current date, it is fresh. I tried applying a formula but this not works for expiry product. Please have a look and guide. Thanks in advance.

`=IF(L6>EDATE(TODAY(),6),"Fresh",IF(L6<EDATE(TODAY(),6),"N.Expire",IF(L6<=TODAY(),"Expire","")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just slightly modify the formula to:

```
=IF(A2>EDATE(TODAY(),6),"Fresh",IF(A2<=TODAY(),"Expire","Near Expire"))
```

[image]